# cannot locate cacti files under /srv/www/cacti

Tags: software-installation, suse, cacti

I am installing `cacti` on SLES-11-SP2 following instructions on [Open Suse Cacti guide](https://en.opensuse.org/cacti)
but I cannot locate the `cacti` files under `/srv/www/cacti` after the installation.
Do you have any idea where they are ?

Comment: Please show us the result of `ls -l /var/www` for this you can [edit] your question.  Also take in consideration to read the [guided tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to know how you should ask things to get a maximum attention and result

Comment: linux-lm73:~/Desktop # ls -l /var/www
ls: cannot access /var/www: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

To locate this folder you can try this as `root`

```
#like suggested in the link you add
find /usr -name cacti 
#If it does not work try this
find / -name cacti 2> /dev/null
```

This command will search for files named cacti in the folder `/usr/`.  then you will be able to identify the root folder of your cacti installation.
The documentation does not mention

Comment: If i run find /usr -name cacti, the results shown is " linux-lm73:~/Desktop # find /usr/ -name cacti
/usr/share/doc/packages/cacti
/usr/share/cacti"                                                          However i am not able to locate this directory  "/srv/www/cacti"

Comment: @user61397 /srv is nothing like a standard directory and I think it stands for the location on your own drive.